# How to upload image from one project to another project laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I have two `laravel` project i use code in my `Myfirstproject` to upload to `Mysecondproject` `public\src\img\upload directory`.

I try these code in Myfirstproject:

```
if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
         $destinationPath='Mysecondproject\public\src\img\upload';
            if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $name);
                    $images[] = $name;
                }
           }
      }
```

But it's not working, any solution for these?

Comment: Try absolute path in $destinationPath and see if it works.

Comment: @KamalSoni what is absolute path?

Comment: The full complete/absolute path `C:\Mysecondproject\public\src\img\upload` or `D:\Mysecondproject\public\src\img\upload` instead of the relative path that you have used in your script, which it does not seem to find.

Comment: @KamalSoni: that's working. but one question if we hosting these two projects there is a problem with specific path like C:\......some path....

Comment: Both the projects need to be on the same server to be make it work or you might have to do NFS mount which can be more trickier. If you have both the projects on the same server you can just put the path in some config file, which can be easy to change whenever you want to, instead of looking for this file.

Comment: @KamalSoni: Ok, thanks you very much

Comment: @KamalSoni you can create answer i will mark it as correct answer

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try absolute path in $destinationPath as `C:\Mysecondproject\public\src\img\upload` or `D:\Mysecondproject\public\src\img\upload`.

Comment: Thank you very much